# How to exclude deprecated classes from Sonar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, sonarqube, sonarlint

i want to exlude all deprecated classes from sonar:

```
<sonar.exclusions>TODO</sonar.exclusions>
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your sonar.properties file.

```
sonar.exclusions= .github/*, **/enums/*,**/exception/**/*
```